# Laravel not displaying errors (homestead)

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Ok, I wasn't able to find anything so my first question on this awesome forum.

I am trying to run one of my friend's project. So I installed homestead, everything works fine but I am getting blank page with just

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

Strange thing is, It gave me few errors before succesful migration. Those errors are in my debugbar and my debugbar folder now doens't show any new errors.

- It's Laravel 5.2.
- config/app debug option is set to true
- I've tried php artisan optimize in my app's directory on my Vagrant box

Thanks for any help. I love this place.

Comment: I think you are asking about app.php ```'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),``` find out APP_DEBUG and set it to true.

Comment: I have it exactly like that. No problem there.

Comment: check your php.ini may be you need to change it to display all errors, not 100% sure, but may be and sorry but no good idea about homestead .

Comment: I am running it on homestead and other apps show errors so it cannot be this issue. No problem thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you open the network tab and post all response headers?

Comment: Now thats interesting. I am getting Status Code:500 Internal Server Error. Dont know why though..

Comment: And response header:
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 01 Sep 2016 19:55:47 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.1

Not sure if it is what you want. Still pretty new to this.

Comment: Could you show nginx/php logs?

Comment: Solved. @PrafullaKumarSahu was right actually. I had 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true) but forget to set it to true at .env file as well. I feel stupid.

Comment: @jbrychta you can verify my answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

As the problem is solved , for future visitors 
   set APP_DEBUG true.

```
  'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)
```

solved the problem for @jbrychta .